# dplyr: add new variables in summarise for each variable name in a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this chunk of code:

```
trimmedMeans <- cleaned %>%
    filter(TrackName == t & ToBeTrimmed != 1) %>%
    group_by(TrackName, SpeakerName) %>%
    summarise(Expectation.Mean = mean(Expectation, na.rm = TRUE),
              Expectation.Sd = sd(Expectation, na.rm = TRUE),
              Interesting.Mean = mean(Interesting, na.rm = TRUE),
              Interesting.Sd = sd(Interesting, na.rm = TRUE),
              Useful.Mean = mean(Useful, na.rm = TRUE),
              Useful.Sd = sd(Useful, na.rm = TRUE),
              OralPresentation.Mean = mean(OralPresentation, na.rm = TRUE),
              OralPresentation.Sd = sd(OralPresentation, na.rm = TRUE),
              NumOfVoters = n()
    )
```

Now supposing to have this vector:

```
myvars <- c("Expectation", "Interesting", "Useful", "OralPresentation")
```

I'd like to generalize the previous chunk of code using the vector `myvars` dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [`summarise_at`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) just for this:

```
iris
  %>% group_by(Species)
  %>% summarise_at(c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"), funs(mean, sd), na.rm=TRUE)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Species    Sepal.Length_mean Sepal.Width_mean Sepal.Length_sd Sepal.Width_sd
  <fct>                  <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>
1 setosa                  5.01             3.43           0.352          0.379
2 versicolor              5.94             2.77           0.516          0.314
3 virginica               6.59             2.97           0.636          0.322
```

Comment: Just to nit-pick;-) `summarise_at` is not that new (anymore), it replaced `summarise_each` in [May 2016](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1845).

Comment: @MauritsEvers Ok, that's a nice notice. :D

Comment: In my example there is also "NumOfVoters = n()". Is there a fast way to add this aggregate in the same statement?

Comment: Solved in this way:

`trimmedMeans <- cleaned %>%
    filter(TrackName == t & ToBeTrimmed != 1) %>%
    group_by(TrackName, SpeakerName) %>%
    add_tally() %>%
    group_by(TrackName, SpeakerName, n, add = FALSE) %>%
    summarise_at(.vars = speaker.characteristcs, funs(mean, sd), na.rm=TRUE)`